# getting control ID inside repeater by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have Entries I want to comment on them . So I created a Repeater with a TextBox and a 
Button inside it . How can I get the id of the button and textbox for specific row by
Jquery ?

```
<ASP:REPEATER runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

...
// Entries: bind data from DB

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />  

</ItemTemplate>
</ASP:REPEATER>
```

Thanks .

Comment: You should post some code. and how are your trying to get the button/textbox id? is it when the user clicks at the button a specific row?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  What jQuery do you have so far?  Show us some code....

Comment: Sorry . I have edited the question.

Comment: So, I have a number of entries. Each entry can be commented on . So, the user write a comment and click the button and a comment will be saved for this specific entry.

Comment: Saved? Where? If you're looking at posting back you should read this: [How to: Respond to Button Events in DataList or Repeater Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df6hth3s.aspx) and use [`FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to find your `TextBox` for the current row.

Comment: saved to the database (using jquery.ajax & web method) . There will be no postback for the button .

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem is that your asp repeater control is going to generate ids like this `ct100_repeater_txt1` which isn't going to help you get that comment associated with its corresponding db row

The common way I have found to accomplish this (which is a pretty standard way I believe) is to assign the elements id with the row id from the database, or if you have no control over the id, to create a custom attribute.

Pseudo code I have used looks something like this: (I'll try and make it language/platform agnostic so you can learn the concept, as opposed to only the language)

```
<repeater template>
    <textbox id="txt1" dbid='<% eval database id>'/>
    <button id="btn1"  dbid='<% eval database id>'/>
</repeater template>
```

that should generate code that looks like:

```
<input type="textbox" value="" id="ct100_txt1" dbid="14" />
<input type="button value="submit" id="ct100_btn1" dbid="14" />

<input type="textbox" value="" id="ct100_txt2" dbid="12" />
<input type="button value="submit" id="ct100_btn2" dbid="12" />

<input type="textbox" value="" id="ct100_txt3" dbid="39" />
<input type="button value="submit" id="ct100_btn3" dbid="39" />
```

Then in whatever language you want you can read from that attribute:

```
Button.Click{
   get attribute dbid of button clicked;
   save text of textbox of same dbid to a database;
}
```

Many cheers! Hope that works for ya

**EDIT**

In response the the comment "where do id save the dbid?!" I'm assuming in a database :) *How* should you save it? There are lots of ways. Here's one you could try with jquery:

create a javascript function to save answers that takes a parameter. when you bind the dbid to the control, bind it into an onclick function and pass that id to the function. The function then gets the text where the dbid matches and saves the comment and id to a database.

```
<textbox dbid="14" />
<input onclick="doStuff(14)" />
<script>
    function doStuff(var id){
        var comment = $('textbox[dbid=id]').value();
        ajax(your url and arguments);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: ok I get the concept . But where do I save dbid for the textbox and button !?

Comment: Edited post to answer your question

Comment: of course in a database :) . What I meant is what bdid is ? is it the control id ? and if it is the record number in db how I link it to a specific control . thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Without more information this is the best I can offer you:

for html like this (which is how asp.net will render your button/textbox):

```
<div id="row1"><button type="button">Click Me!</button><input type="text" name="tb_info" /></div>
<div id="row2"><button type="button">Click Me again!</button><input type="text" name="tb_info" /></div>
```

You could select the `button and textbox for specific row` by using the following jQuery:

```
$("#row1 > button, #row1 > input")
```

Comment: rows (records) are bound from database . So, I do not know their IDs .